# AdventureWorks Database installation script Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am installing the `AdventureWorks 2008` sample database from [here](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/89502). I am executing the following script in SQL Server 2008 in `SQLCMD` mode, but getting the error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 28
>   Incorrect syntax near ':'.
>   Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1600.22 (X64) Jul  9 2008 14:17:44
>   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation Developer
>   Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7600: )
>
> Started - 2013-04-07 10:46:30.423
>   * Dropping Database
>   * Creating Database
>
> Msg 5105, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
>   A file activation error occurred. The physical file name
>   '$(SqlSamplesDatabasePath)AdventureWorks2008_Data.mdf' may be
>   incorrect. Diagnose and correct additional errors, and retry the
>   operation.
>
> Msg 1802, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   CREATE DATABASE failed.
>   Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
>
> Msg 5011, Level 14, State 5, Line 2
>   User does not have permission to alter
>   database 'AdventureWorks2008', the database does not exist, or the
>   database is not in a state that allows access checks.
>
> Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   ALTER DATABASE statement failed.
>
> Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Database 'AdventureWorks2008' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.  .  .

This is part of the script I'm using:

```
/*============================================================================
  File:     instawdb.sql

  Summary:  Creates the AdventureWorks 2008R2 OLTP sample database.

  SQL Server Version: 10.50.1600
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  This file is part of the Microsoft SQL Server Code Samples.

  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

  This source code is intended only as a supplement to Microsoft
  Development Tools and/or on-line documentation.  See these other
  materials for detailed information regarding Microsoft code samples.

  All data in this database is ficticious.

  THIS CODE AND INFORMATION ARE PROVIDED "AS IS" WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY
  KIND, EITHER EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE
  IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND/OR FITNESS FOR A
  PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
============================================================================*/

-- Be sure to enable FULL TEXT SEARCH before running this script

-->> WARNING: THIS SCRIPT MUST BE RUN IN SQLCMD MODE INSIDE SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO. <<--
:on error exit

-- IMPORTANT
/*
 * In order to run this script manually, either set the environment variables,
 * or uncomment the setvar statements and provide the necessary values if
 * the defaults are not correct for your installation.
 */

setvar SqlSamplesDatabasePath   "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA"
setvar SqlSamplesSourceDataPath "C:\Users\DEVESH\Downloads\"

IF '$(SqlSamplesSourceDataPath)' IS NULL OR '$(SqlSamplesSourceDataPath)' = ''
BEGIN
    RAISERROR(N'The variable SqlSamplesSourceDataPath must be defined.', 16, 127) WITH NOWAIT
    RETURN
END

IF '$(SqlSamplesDatabasePath)' IS NULL OR '$(SqlSamplesDatabasePath)' = ''
BEGIN
    RAISERROR(N'The variable SqlSamplesDatabasePath must be defined.', 16, 127) WITH NOWAIT
    RETURN
END

SET NOCOUNT OFF;
GO

PRINT CONVERT(varchar(1000), @@VERSION);
GO

PRINT '';
PRINT 'Started - ' + CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 121);
GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be that you're not running it in SQLCMD Mode like the script warns:

```
-->> WARNING: THIS SCRIPT MUST BE RUN IN SQLCMD MODE INSIDE SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO. <<--
```

See http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2405/sql-server-management-studio-sqlcmd-mode-option/ for information on how to switch to SQLCMD mode inside of SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: it is showing error :-Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 28
Incorrect syntax near ':'.Is it Correct :- :on error exit?

Comment: Yes, that syntax is fine (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165702(v=sql.105).aspx). I suspect you aren't actually running it in SQL command mode?

Comment: I have gone to query menu-> and then clicked on sqlcmd mode..and then execute..Is it fine?